# How to change a variable state with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, setstate

I have a `user_id` on my state, it's looks as :

```
this.state ={id_user:''}
```

I want to get this id_user from another component, I develop it like that :

```
handleAjouter = (id_user) => {
    this.setState({
      openPopupAjout: true,
      id_user: id_user
    });
    console.log(id_user, this.state.id_user)
  }
```

When I run it, I get on the console :

- `id_user: 1258`
- `this.state.id_user: it's empty value`

But when I change the method `handleAjouter` to this :

```
handleAjouter = (id_user) => {
    this.state.id_user = id_user;
    this.setState({
      openPopupAjout: true
    });
    console.log(id_user, this.state.id_user)
  }
```

I get on the console :

- `id_user: 1258`
- `this.state.id_user: 1258`

But, I get also `Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()`

How can I fix it ?

Comment: `setState` maybe asynchronous. It is not immediately updated after `this.setState`. Pass a callback as second argument and log in that.   `this.setState({
      openPopupAjout: true,
      id_user: id_user
    },() => console.log(this.state.id_user));`

Comment: setState is asynchronous, and takes an optional callback

Comment: @MaheerAli thank you, it works well, you can add it as a answer.

Comment: @CodeLover Glad to know it helped. There is not point to answer the question if duplicate or comment solved your problem. If you have any other problem feel free to ask

Comment: @MaheerAli How can I change the state of table looks as : `this.state.tranches[0].end = end;`

Comment: @CodeLover Try `this.setState({tranches:[{end},...this.state.tranches]})`